# Htaccess modification for ignoring Querystring completely

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue where I'm using Wordpress + W3 Total Cache + .htaccess + mod_rewrite.

Every querystring variable appended to a URL is causing Wordpress + Total Cache to re-cache a unique file for the request.  I know of this Question that was asked but when using it, I feel like I'm not modifying my .htaccess file correctly - [Redirection / htaccess rule to kill off query strings to use wordpress super cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757252/redirection-htaccess-rule-to-kill-off-query-strings-to-use-wordpress-super-cac)

What is the correct way to modify the `.htaccess` file below to support ignoring all querystring variables but letting them be read by javascript on the page:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before all of your existing rules, but after any rules that you have redirecting (has an `R` flag), try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /[^\ \?]*\?[^\ ]+
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /teamin/index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

This is i use in apache 2.4 ,you can try it !